# Use testnet chain config when starting node

Tags: go-ethereum, mobile-wallet

I'm following the instructions for creating an Android mobile client from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mobile-Clients:-Libraries-and-Inproc-Ethereum-Nodes).  I have successfully started a node but I'm not sure which chain I'm connected to.  My guess is its mainnet instead of testnet.

How would I go about connecting to the testnet instead of the mainnet?  I have tried 
`ChainConfig testnet = Geth.gettestnetChainConfig();` but can't find any functions which take a ChainConfig as an argument.  I've scoured the go code as well.